# Copy and paste Excel tables and charts into a Word template with specific bookmarks: 5941 error selected objects don't exist

Tags: excel, vba

I inherited a macro that copies and pastes Excel tables and charts into a Word template with specific bookmarks.

The original macro ran.

I edited the macro to include another sheet (Sheet4_new) in Excel and then edited the Word template by adding a page with Sheet4_new bookmarks.

Now the macro pastes some of the tables and charts (including the ones from the sheet I added) but says that other charts don't exist, but they are still in the macro and Word template.

The debugger highlights this line:

```
myDoc.Bookmarks(ChartBookmarkArray(BookmarkCounter)).Range.Select
```

It's only select charts and tables that are not pasting into the Word template.

Here is the inherited macro:

```vb
'Array for the various tabs of interest
    TabArray = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4_new", "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "Sheet7", "Sheet8", "Sheet9")`
  
'Arrays to switch between tables and charts of interest
    TableArray = Array("J15:L24", "A4:I14", "I16:K23", "B4:H15")
    ChartArray = Array("Chart 1", "Chart 2")
    
'List of Word Document Bookmarks (To Paste To)
    TableBookmarkArray = Array("Sheet1", "Sheet1Table", "Sheet2", "Sheet2Table", "Sheet3", "Sheet3Table", "Sheet4_new", "Sheet4_newTable", "Sheet5", "Sheet5Table", "Sheet6", "Sheet6Table", "Sheet7", "Sheet7Table", "BlankTable", "Sheet8", "Sheet9", "Sheet9Table")
    ChartBookmarkArray = Array("Sheet1Chart", "Sheet1Chart2", "Sheet2Chart", "Sheet2Chart2", "Sheet3Chart", "Sheet3Chart2", "Sheet4_newChart", "Sheet4_newChart2", "Sheet5Chart", "Sheet5Chart2", "BlankChart", "BlankChart", "BlankChart", "BlankChart", "Sheet8Chart", "Sheet8Chart2", "Sheet9Chart", "Sheet9Chart2")
 
  
'Variable for cycling through all the tables and charts in both arrays at the same time
    BookmarkCounter = 1

'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

'Set Variable Equal To Destination Word Document
    Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    WordApp.Visible = True
    WordApp.Activate
    WordFilePath = "locationoncomputer"
    Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(WordFilePath & "nameofdoc.docx")
   

'Loop Through and Copy/Paste Multiple Excel Tables and Charts
    For x = LBound(TabArray) To UBound(TabArray)`
    
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(TabArray(x)).Activate

        If x = 2 Then
            RangeSwitcher = 1
            IsThereSomething = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TabArray(x)).Range("K23").Value
                'ElseIf x = 4 Or x = 5 Then
            'RangeSwitcher = 5
            'IsThereSomething = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TabArray(x)).Range("J19").Value
        Else
            RangeSwitcher = 3
            IsThereSomething = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TabArray(x)).Range("J20").Value
        End If

    'Switch between the two charts and tables in any tab
        For y = 1 To 2
        
            If x <> 7 Then
            'Copy Table Range from Excel
                Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TabArray(x)).Range(TableArray(RangeSwitcher))
                tbl.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
            'Paste Table into MS Word (using inserted Bookmarks -> ctrl+shift+F5) 
                myDoc.Bookmarks(TableBookmarkArray(BookmarkCounter)).Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
                    Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
        
            ElseIf y = 2 Then
                
                Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TabArray(x)).Range(TableArray(RangeSwitcher))
                tbl.CopyPicture Appearance:=xlScreen, Format:=xlPicture
                myDoc.Bookmarks(TableBookmarkArray(BookmarkCounter)).Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteEnhancedMetafile, _
                    Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                    
            End If
                    
       
            For Each iShape In WordApp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
                If iShape.AlternativeText = "" Then
                Set pShape = iShape
                pShape.AlternativeText = "table"
                Exit For
                End If
            Next
            
        
            If x <> 5 And x <> 6 Then
            'Check if there are no counts & costs in the current table selection
                If IsThereSomething = 0 Then
                'If there's no counts or costs for this county, then we put in some replacement text instead of a chart
                    myDoc.Bookmarks(ChartBookmarkArray(BookmarkCounter)).Range.Select
                    myDoc.Bookmarks(ChartBookmarkArray(BookmarkCounter)).Range.Text = NothingReplacementTextArray(BookmarkCounter)
                Else
                'Otherwise, copy the corresponding chart
                    With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(ChartArray(y))
                        .Activate
                        .Select
                    End With
                    ActiveChart.ChartArea.Copy
    
                'Used this at first but it's not that nice looking for charts when they're pasted in
                    'myDoc.Bookmarks(ChartBookmarkArray(BookmarkCounter)).Range.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, _
                    'Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
    
                    myDoc.Bookmarks(ChartBookmarkArray(BookmarkCounter)).Range.Select
                    myDoc.Bookmarks(ChartBookmarkArray(BookmarkCounter)).Range.Text = ""
                    WordApp.ActiveDocument.Application.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=14, _
                        Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
                
                    For Each iShape In WordApp.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes
                        If iShape.AlternativeText = "" Then
                        Set pShape = iShape
                        pShape.ScaleHeight = 65
                        pShape.ScaleWidth = 65
                        pShape.AlternativeText = "chart"
                        Exit For
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            End If

      
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(TabArray(x)).Range("C2").Select

        'Move to the next bookmark in the list
            BookmarkCounter = BookmarkCounter + 1
        'Switch table range to second table on tab
            RangeSwitcher = RangeSwitcher + 1

        Next y
    Next x
```

Tried deleting and re-adding bookmarks, get the same error.

Comment: There are two such lines, can you clarify which one is highlighted when the error occurs? Before that line, add these lines `Debug.Print "BookmarkCounter = " & BookmarkCounter` and `Debug.Print "ChartBookmarkArray = " & ChartBookmarkArray(BookmarkCounter)` and `Debug.Print "Bookmark = " & myDoc.Bookmarks(ChartBookmarkArray(BookmarkCounter)).Name` ... run your code again and then add a comment here on what is printed in the Immediate window and which line now errors

Answer (score 2):

This is the issue:

```
myDoc.Bookmarks(ChartBookmarkArray(BookmarkCounter)).Range.Text = ""
```

Setting a bookmarked range's Text will delete the bookmark.

To illustrate:

```
Dim bm As Bookmark
    
Set bm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Test")
bm.Range.Text = ""
Set bm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Test") 'Error: The requested member of the collection does not exist
```

Here's a solution:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim bm As Bookmark
    
    Set bm = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Test")
    
    'bm.Range.Text = ""     'this will delete the bookmark
    SetBookmarkText bm, ""  '...this will not (effectively)
End Sub

'Set a bookmark's Text; recreate it after it's deleted
Sub SetBookmarkText(bm As Bookmark, txt As String)
    Dim nm As String, rng As Range
    nm = bm.Name
    Set rng = bm.Range
    With rng
        .Text = txt
        .Bookmarks.Add Name:=nm 're-add the bookmark
    End With
End Sub
```